# Alterar propriedade do CSS no TypeScript (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular

Tenho uma lista que quando clicar nela, preciso que o `display: listview` seja trocado para `display: none`.

Minha lista é composta dessa forma:

```
<li class="sub">
     <a class="dropdown-item waves-effect" (click)="verificaPermissao(9, 'confestoque')">
     <i class="mr-3 fa fa-archive"></i>Estoque</a>
</li>
```

Na minha função `verificaPermissão` preciso setar o `display` para `none` quando ocorre o click. Tentei com `nativeElement`:

Constructor:

```
private el: ElementRef
```

Typescript:

```
verificaPermissao(idTela?: number, nomeRota?: string){
     let lista = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".sub"); 
     lista.classList.remove('display')
}
```

Também tentei:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
this.renderer.setElementAttribute(element, "display", "none");
```

Mas recebo:

> ```
>  ERROR TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function
>      at
> ```

Como eu posso acessar a propriedade `display` da minha classe sub?

Comment: Você pode dar bind no atributo hidden passando true ou false:  `<li [hidden]="condicao">...</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for mudar uma popriedade vc pode usar ngStyle se for mais de uma vc pode usar o ngClass

da uma olhada no stackblitz que eu criei:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohu5kw

TS

```
  display = 'listview'

  mudarDisplay(){
    this.display='none';
  }
```

HTML

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'display': display}">teste</p>
<button type="button" (click)="mudarDisplay()">teste</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Questão bem antiga, mas gostaria de ajudar, no angular, pode usar como se fosse uma referência normal do Javascript porém tem que colocar no fim de que elemento se trata, já que o Angular por padrão trás um NodeList e é um HtmlElement, existem várias maneiras de fazer, mas vou deixar essa como exemplo

Vai pegar o elemento dessa forma dentro da função:

```
    let element = document.querySelector('.sub') as HTMLLIElement
```

E manipular assim:

```
    element.style.display = 'none'
```